# Life from Non-living Stuff

Tags: epistemology, ontology, theology

> **The most amazing thing about a living system is that it is made up of non-living atoms and molecules!!!**

This beautiful thought just got me awestruck, the abstract feelings that we have are just some exchange of non-living compounds that indeed control us...

Even myself thinking or writing this text is due to these non-living stuff.

so the saintly *" concept of desires" are a null set* is actually a scientific concept, we let these non-living compounds control ourselves, and maybe one day we know how to control them.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: One molecule of H2O is not wet. Yet, a drop of wastewater is. Systems having emergent properties of that their parts don't have are all around us. What is so mind numbing about the emergent property of life ?

Comment: "the saintly " concept of desires" are a null set is actually a scientific concept" What does it mean ? a "saintly" concept ? And a concept is "a null set" ?

Comment: Saintly means spiritual.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza and a null set is a mathematical term to describe nothing

Comment: The "null set" is **not** nothing: it is an empty set.

Comment: You may want to study Spinoza, Hegel and Ernst Bloch in Western Philosophy.

Comment: Contra the position of these three (sort of) would be Heidegger, Heisenberg and Konrad Lorenz after WW2.

Comment: You could actually make this into a good question. I would just say:  don’t reinvent the wheel. When the libraries open, go there and see who might have had these thoughts before you, or something like them. When you say these non-living things “control us” if, for instance, you are low on potassium and I give you potassium, and save your life, well doctors do things like this every day. A tiny example.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also confused by what you mean by “saintly concept of desire.”  Do you mean “Taṇhā is a Pāli word, which originates from the Vedic Sanskrit word tṛ́ṣṇā, which means "thirst, craving, desire" (Wikipedia) ? 
Taṇhā appears in the Four Noble Truths, wherein taṇhā is the cause of dukkha (suffering, pain, unsatisfactoriness) and the cycle of repeated birth, becoming and death (Saṃsāra).[1][2][4] (Wikipedia)?

In the West this might be referred to as human Will or just Will. And we have problems with this going back at least to the Prometheus (myth).

The human Will pushes back necessity and expands freedom but there are dangers in this. Like Heidegger said, only a God can save us, [but for that to be so, we can’t will the God, See A. Megill, Prophets of Extremity, (1985)].

Comment: yups, you just gave a more elaborate explanation to the saintly concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the curiosity in you regarding the relation between living and non-living things.

You must have noticed the organism--virus that comes in between living and non-living things. Of course there is an '*invisible link*' between these two (living and non-living) and that is not often taught as a part of academic studies.  The Upanishads will help you to clear your doubt.

You may have heard about one of the *mahavaakyas* (Tat Tvam Asi) and the story behind that *vaakya* https://hridaya-yoga.com/hridaya-yoga-articles/teachings-from-the-upanishads/tat-tvam-asi-you-are-that-chandogya-upanishad/

Modern science will teach you about chemicals, molecules, atoms, subatomic particles and also almost about everything. But when it **enters 'life' from non-living** atoms/molecules/compounds it will grope in the dark. This type of study will not take you to the route you need. What we get from academic studies is a peripheral view about the link between living things and non-living things.

You might have heard about *Pancha-bhoota* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancha_Bhoota and this will help you to understand about creation. Try to understand more about it from reliable sources. But while going through them please don't take them as a small amount of earth, water etc.